# Get Level in MDX Query for each axis with Mondrian

Tags: mdx, mondrian

Using Mondrian, I would like to get Level in MDX query for each axis.

For example :

> SELECT NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[Product].[Product Family].Members})} ON COLUMNS
>
> NON EMPTY CrossJoin([Time].[Quarter].Members, [Store].[Store Name].Members) ON ROWS
>
> FROM [Sales]
>
> WHERE {Hierarchize({[Measures].[Unit Sales]})}

Expected results are :

COLUMNS : [Product].[Product Family]

ROWS : [Time].[Quarter], [Store].[Store Name]

Recently I used this code :

> axes[i].getSet().getType().getLevel()

It worked for the COLUMNS axis, but it doesn't work for the ROWS axis.
I suppose this is caused by the arity in ROWS axis which is more than 1.

Is there any way to get the level in an axis which has arity more than 1 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
with
member [Product].[Product Family].[Row current member] as
[Time].[Quarter].currentmember.name + ', ' +
[Store].[Store Name].currentmember.name
```

then in select clause include the member in column axis:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY Hierarchize({[Product].[Product Family].Members,
                 [Product].[Product Family].[Row current member]}) ON COLUMNS

NON EMPTY CrossJoin([Time].[Quarter].Members, [Store].[Store Name].Members) ON ROWS

FROM [Sales]

WHERE {Hierarchize({[Measures].[Unit Sales]})}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Anyway, the query is already given so I should not modify it. All I need is to extract the information of the level for each element in each axis.